# How to effectively log from PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, emr

I'm wondering what the best practice is for logging from `Spark` (using Pyspark) on an `EMR` cluster.  We'd like to have some kind of feedback that we can check on to see how a job is doing, and not have to wait till the job either fails or completes to know.

Comment: What about the SparkUI?

Comment: Or, more programmatically, using the REST API http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html